# Replace a json value using regex

Tags: java, string

```
String inputJson = "{\r\n" + 
            "  \"fullName\" : \"Hamo\",\r\n" + 
            "  \"staff\" : false,\r\n" + 
            "  \"supr\" : true,\r\n" + 
            "  \"permissions\" : [ \"Perm1\", \"Perm2\" ],\r\n" + 
            "  \"services\" : [ \"Serv1\", \"Serv2\" ],\r\n" + 
            "  \"authToken\" : \"1234567890abcdefghaijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\",\r\n" + 
            "  \"customerId\" : 12345,\r\n" + 
            "  \"clients\" : [ 1, 3, 8 ],\r\n" + 
            "  \"wts\" : false,\r\n" + 
            //yyyy-MM-dd
            "  \"testDate\" : \"1982-09-21\"\r\n" + 
            "}";
```

I need to replace authToken value with another string using regex.
This question was edited because it was not asked properly.

Comment: Could you expand on *why* you can't use a JSON library? That would be the obvious approach that would avoid any number of possible corner case bugs.

Comment: First, why is deserialization not an option? How are you processing this JSON after?

Comment: Deserialization is always an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a JSON class there remains:

```
inputJson = inputJson.replaceFirst("(\"authToken\"\\s*:\\s*\")[^\"]*\"",
    "$1" + authToken + "\"");
```

This assumes that the authToken does not contain a dollar `$`.

Comment: Nothing better than getting an answer without having to answer 10 questions myself. You sir are a hero.

Comment: @AbdulahPehlic True, but if people are asking questions it usually means there's an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) or not enough information has been provided

Comment: Understood, next time i'll pay more attention to that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @AbdulahPehlic I am a bit ashamed of my simplistic answer, but the question was clear: without much JSON ado. And I think it is a valid approach, minor overhead. One thing: you are right about XY: it would have been better to construct the JSON; patching the authentication token seems an afterthought, when all is build.

Comment: @JoopEggen I think you wanted to address byxor, not abdullah

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yeah (no risk with your user name). The mention of XY problem mixed me up.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using convenient json-editing libraries, you can use regexp:

```java
String inputJson = "{\r\n" +
        "  \"fullName\" : \"Hamo\",\r\n" +
        "  \"staff\" : false,\r\n" +
        "  \"supr\" : true,\r\n" +
        "  \"permissions\" : [ \"Perm1\", \"Perm2\" ],\r\n" +
        "  \"services\" : [ \"Serv1\", \"Serv2\" ],\r\n" +
        "  \"authToken\" : \"1234567890abcdefghaijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\",\r\n" +
        "  \"customerId\" : 12345,\r\n" +
        "  \"clients\" : [ 1, 3, 8 ],\r\n" +
        "  \"wts\" : false,\r\n" +
        //yyyy-MM-dd
        "  \"testDate\" : \"1982-09-21\"\r\n" +
        "}";

String desiredAuthToken = "anyAuthTokenYouWant";
inputJson.replaceAll("(\"authToken\"\\s*:\\s*\")\\w*", "$1" + desiredAuthToken);
```

Here's the explanation:

```
"(\"authToken\"\\s*:\\s*\")\\w*";
 (                              – start of a first capturing group
  \"authToken\"                 – matches "authToken" string
               \\s*             – 0 to N whitespaces (including normal spaces, tabulations, etc.)
                   :            – matches a single colon
                    \\s*        – 0 to N whitespaces again
                        )       – end of the capturing group
                         \\w*   – matches 0 to N alphanumeric characters. You may want to replace it with a different regexp, that suits you needs in a better way.
```

Finally, you are replacing the whole matching expression with `"$1" + desiredAuthToken`, where `$1` is basically the contents of a first capture group. (It is `\"authToken\" : \"` in this case).

Comment: Well, while I was slowly typing and testing the answer, @joop-eggen has already answered the question. That's what 87k reputation for! :D